# Avoid SecurityException because of "No active admin owned by"

Tags: android, admin, securityexception

How to avoid this Exception

```
E/AndroidRuntime(26113): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: No active admin owned by uid XXXX for policy #3
```

when calling this:

```
public static void lockScreen(Context context) {
    Log.d(TAG, "lockScreen");
    ComponentName mDeviceAdminSample = null;
    DevicePolicyManager dpm = (DevicePolicyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
    intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mDeviceAdminSample);
    dpm.lockNow();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I got the same error as OP. Since only combination of other answers helped me, here is my walk through to make the OP code sample work:

1. Make sure you have created device admin receiver and xml policy file as described in https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html
2. Add admin receiver with xml policy file reference to Manifest.
3. Install your app
4. Enable app as admin in Setting>Security>Device administrators>"Your app admin receiver label value"
5. or do [4] programmatically

   ```
   mDeviceAdminSample = new ComponentName(this,DeviceAdminSampleReceiver.class);
   Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
   intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mDeviceAdminSample);
   currActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
   ```

Answer (score 5):

You have to install and enable a device administrator as described in the reference docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

Answer (score 3):

you are missing this below line.

```
mDeviceAdminSample = new ComponentName(this, DeviceAdminSampleReceiver.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

Notice how the lines:

```
        Intent it = new         Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
        it.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, new ComponentName(this, YourAdminReceiver.class));
        startActivityForResult(it, 0);
```

can be skipped. If you do not want your users to allow the app to lock the screen there is the alternative way:

```
adb shell dpm set-device-owner com.package/.YourAdminReceiver
```

Now what does this have to do with the SecurityException the OP was encountering ?

Well, I already had the device owner set to  `com.package/.YourAdminReceiver` via the adb shell way, but for different purposes than screen locking. When I have added the `<force-lock>` tag to my device-admin.xml:

```
<uses-policies>
        <limit-password />
        <reset-password />
        <force-lock />
    </uses-policies>
```

I was naturally expecting my `locknow()` API call to work, but instead it hasn't. I got the `SecurityException` just as OP did. Strange, given that my app was already the admin and owner of the device. I have made it work by unsetting from the device owner role, uninstalling it and then reinstalling it. Be advised that once set as a device owner via adb shell, an app can only be unset from that role from code:

```
//        mDpm.clearDeviceOwnerApp(getPackageName());
//        mDpm.removeActiveAdmin(deviceAdmin);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the device admin was part of an instrumentation tests rather than my app itself. Turned out to be a bug in the way Android handles permissions. The fix was to move the device admin class, manifest and policies into the target app. Certainly not ideal, but I can't see a way around it.

Answer (score 0):

You would need 3 thing to do :

1. add `<receiver>` to AndroidManifest
2. make new xml file for `<device-admin>`
3. make new .kt file for `DeviceAdminReceiver`

Here is a link from an answer I already did (with example code) : [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67816111/4160896)

A reference from [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html#developing)