# How to create a Device Administrator in Android

Tags: android

All of us must have seen under 'Device Administrator' The list of Administrators.

They can perform special tasks.

Any Ideas how to create an app that can become device Admin?

This is just a research, don't take tension!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The process is described in depth in the [Device Administration guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) in the Android developer documentation.

At a high level, the steps are:

- Create a [`DeviceAdminReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminReceiver.html) and register it in your manifest
- Launch an Intent with the [`ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN) action, and pass your receiver as the `DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN,` extra.

Once the user has accepted your device as a device administrator, you can perform a limited set of device administration actions in your application.

Comment: Thanks sir. I'll try, then inform you.

Comment: For what it's worth, a more detailed article on how to create a basic device administrator (with code and screen-shots) can be found here: https://androidadministrator.com/?p=82

Answer (score 2):

you research more info [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) documentation or [device management policies](http://developer.android.com/training/enterprise/device-management-policy.html)

Answer (score 1):

You would need 3 thing to do :

1. add `<receiver>` to AndroidManifest
2. make new xml file for `<device-admin>`
3. make new .kt file for `DeviceAdminReceiver`

**Example :**

in *AndroidManifest.xml* (inside `<activity>`, add the code below) :

```
<receiver
        android:name=".MyDeviceAdminReceiver"
        android:description="@string/app_name"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.device_admin"
            android:resource="@xml/device_owner_receiver" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

in *device_owner_receiver.xml*, add this code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<device-admin>
    <uses-policies>
        <limit-password />
        <watch-login />
        <reset-password />
        <force-lock />
        <wipe-data />
        <expire-password />
        <encrypted-storage />
        <disable-camera />
    </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

in *MyDeviceAdminReceiver.kt*, add the code below :

```
class MyDeviceAdminReceiver : DeviceAdminReceiver() {
    override fun onEnabled(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        super.onEnabled(context, intent)
        Toast.makeText(context, "Admin is enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

When you run the app after adding the code at the top, the app will prompt an admin request.

For reference from, [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html#developing).